# How to remove a property from document - mongo / loopback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopback

I have an old property on one of my models, and I'd like to remove it from all the documents in a collection.  I've tried posting via /upsertWithWhere using the id to update by:

- passing in undefined for the value which results in "http error 400 bad request"
- passing in null which just sets the property to null

I also was thinking I could do a regular POST and just overwrite each document, but these particular documents are large and I'd rather not do that.

**Is there a way to simply patch it?**

Edit:  Need an answer that implements this Via the Loopback API.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick:

```
db.collection('collection_name').update({},{$unset: {"old_property": ""}}, {multi:true})
```

Obviously, just make sure you insert into "old_property" the field name of that old property.

Explaining the query a little further...

1. "{}" matches all documents in the collection
2. "{$unset: {"old_property": ""}" removes the field(s) specified
3. "{multi:true}" (An optional field for update) Allows you to update multiple documents when set to true

Used this as a reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter

Comment: This seems like it would do the trick, however I'm looking for a way to do it with loopback.