# Mongo.exe command line argument on removing a property on a collection of documents gives a syntax error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to remove a property on a collection of documents in a MongoDb via the command line in Windows.

Command Line:

```
mongo MyDbName --eval 'db.getCollection("Equipment").update({},{$unset:{"TestId": ""}},{multi:true})'
```

Gives:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shell eval):1:0
```

But I just followed what are in:

```
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/
```

and

[How to remove a property from document - mongo / loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448546/how-to-remove-a-property-from-document-mongo-loopback)

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: There nothing wrong with "what you have posted in the question". The specific error of `unterminated string literal` however means that you are **actually** submitting something else, and probably constructed within it's own script which does not correctly balance the quotation marks, or does not use the differing types of quotation marks in all places as your example above does. So the error is with code that is not actually included in the question. We can't help unless we see the code that really produces the problem. The snippet provided does not.

Comment: Strange, I did not submit anything else than that.

Comment: Bottom line is I can copy and paste your command and it will execute without error. It won't do anything because I don't have the same database or collection names of course, but the error is a "syntax error" and does not come from the snippet posted in this question.

Comment: I believe you. That is why it is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you but is there any reason that you need to execute it from the dos command line?  Can you start a mongo shell and execute directly there?